# Can I fool HttpRequest.Current.Request.IsLocal?

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext

I'm running a web application that displays some debugging behavior if it's being run locally - quotes around resource strings, etc - and I'd like to demo the application on my laptop at a conference where I won't have internet access, so it has to be local.

The application uses HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal to determine if it's running locally - is there any way to fool it? I'd like to trick it into returning "False" even though I am indeed running locally.

I do have access to the source code (and realize I could just demo a build where the "IsLocal" check is commented out), but would rather not make a special build for this demo. If need be, I'll do that, but I'd rather use the existing codebase untouched.

Comment: Deploy it to another server on the same network.

Comment: I'm using this installation for a non-networked demo of the application, and I'll only have my laptop there. I toyed with a virtual machine on my laptop, though I'm afraid the speed would hamper my demo.

Comment: It may be hard to fool `IsLocal` itself, but an attacker may not need to. You still have to keep things like [CSRF attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_\(CSRF\)) in mind, where _your local browser itself_ is fooled into doing malicious things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would require spoofing a non-local IP address in requests to your local instance of IIS. I think you'd probably spend less time just making a demo build than trying to make that work.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, but I was thinking I'd have to go that route. I just thought there might be something quick I'd overlooked.

Answer (score 21):

Request.IsLocal property implements the following code :

```
public bool IsLocal { 
            get {
                String remoteAddress = UserHostAddress; 

                // if unknown, assume not local
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(remoteAddress))
                    return false; 

                // check if localhost 
                if (remoteAddress == "127.0.0.1" || remoteAddress == "::1") 
                    return true;
 
                // compare with local address
                if (remoteAddress == LocalAddress)
                    return true;
 
                return false;
            }
```

Source : Decompiled source code (Microsoft : [referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/WorkerRequest.cs,ab8517882440da8b) )

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

*I believe this is true, but cannot verify right now.*

IsLocal returns True when the site is bound to the loopback address 127.0.0.1.

If you make sure in IIS that your website is bound to one of your machine's non-loopback addresses (i.e. 192.168.1.100), then IsLocal should return False.

Cassini, by definition, is always local, since it can only bind to the loopback address.

Comment: I had a glimmer of hope, but this doesn't seem to work in my environment - either IIS6 or 7. Can you please give this a shot when you have a chance, and if you can get it to work, I'd love to know how.

Comment: If its bound to `192.168.1.100` then the `remoteAddress == LocalAddress` (as remote will be `192.168.1.100` too) check will be true so it'll return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

If your server has multiple ip addresses, you'll need some extra code. The following handles multiple ip addresses, and handles CDN like cloudflare which will have the wrong ip address in the Request.UserHostAddress property.

Code:

```
private bool IsLocal()
{
    if (Request.IsLocal)
    {
        return true;
    }
    string forwardIP = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    foreach (NetworkInterface netInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        IPInterfaceProperties ipProps = netInterface.GetIPProperties();
        foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation addr in ipProps.UnicastAddresses)
        {
            string ipString = addr.Address.ToString();
            if (Request.UserHostAddress == ipString || forwardIP == ipString)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR can be spoofed, so if you aren't using a CDN it is probably better to remove it entirely.